# QT Stylesheet for HLine/VLine color

Tags: css, qt, stylesheet

I'm pretty new to this Qt thing and its whole stylesheet system. My background of HTML/CSS helps a little to understand the system, but a lot of things just happens for no apparent reason....or don't happen.

Anyway, the mystery of the HLINE and the VLINE and how to change the lines' color is just a mystery for me. I learned from other questions and various fora that it's linked to the QFrame  elements. And I can change the color of the line if I just use something like

```
QFrame
{
color: red;
}
```

But this of course changes the color of tons of other things that uses a QFrame as well. I could of course go into the HLINE element and put `color: red;` in there and that works fine, but my app requires that I put everything in a single stylesheet that gets loaded into the app. So styling individual elements is not an option.

A solution would look something like

```
QFrame HLine, QFrame VLine
{
color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
QFrame[frameShape="4"] /* QFrame::HLine == 0x0004 */
{
    color: red;
}

QFrame[frameShape="5"] /* QFrame::VLine == 0x0005 */
{
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: Note: `color` only works if the [frameShadow](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qframe.html#Shadow-enum) is set to `Plain` -- the default for HLine and VLine is [QFrame::Sunken](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qframe.html#picture). See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 15):

`HLine` and `VLine` are tricky to style. It's worth taking a look at the "[Detailed Description](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qframe.html#details)" section of the documentation. For a quick fix, I found that this set of rules allows customizing the appearance of such lines via stylesheet in a reliable and relatively clean manner:

```
QFrame[frameShape="4"],
QFrame[frameShape="5"]
{
    border: none;
    background: red;
}
```

This works regardless of the `frameShadow` property, which otherwise affects their appearance and the effect of style rules. Keep in mind that the width of the lines are **not** 1px by default -- this can be changed using the `min-width`, `max-width`, `min-height` or `max-height` properties, as appropriate.

For a more detailed overview of my findings, read along.

---

Most `QFrame`s have the [QFrame::Plain](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qframe.html#Shape-enum) frameShape by default, but `HLine` and `VLine`'s default frameShape is `QFrame::Sunken`. This means that they are not really lines, but thin boxes that contain a mid-line that's used to provide the 3D effect. From the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qframe.html#details):

> The mid-line width specifies the width of an extra line in the middle of the frame, which uses a third color to obtain a special 3D effect. Notice that a mid-line is only drawn for Box, HLine and VLine frames that are raised or sunken.

If you set the frameShape to Plain, this midline is still visible, and can be styled with the `color` property (note: that's *not* a `background-color` or `border-color`!)

But this doesn't work for a HLine/VLine that's left with the default Sunken appearance. One way to fix this could be to set separate styles for Plain and Sunken QFrames by using attribute selectors with the decimal values of the property enums (which are described in the documentation in hehadecimal), like so:

```
/* Reference (from doc.qt.io/qt-5/qframe.html#types):
 * - frameShape[4] --> QFrame::HLine = 0x0004
 * - frameShape[5] --> QFrame::VLine = 0x0005
 * - frameShadow[16] --> QFrame::Plain = 0x0010 (default for most widgets)
 * - frameShadow[48] --> QFrame::Sunken = 0x0030 (default for HLine/VLine)
 */
QFrame[frameShape="4"][frameShadow="16"],
QFrame[frameShape="5"][frameShadow="16"]
{
    ...
}

QFrame[frameShape="4"][frameShadow="48"],
QFrame[frameShape="5"][frameShadow="48"]
{
    ...
}
```

but since the styles that work for HLine/VLine with QFrame::Sunken also work for those with `QFrame::Plain`, it's usually a waste to do so. I show them above for educational value only about how to use attribute selectors.

The best approach is to treat the QFrame as the box that it is, and either (1) set `border-top` or `border-right` coupled with a `max-height: 0px` (or `max-width` for a VLine), to ensure the inside of the box doesn't take up space in the layout; or (2) use a background color coupled with `border: none` (in which case, max-height/width should be 1 or larger, otherwise the QFrame is invisible). The latter is the solution I'd recommend, as shown in the first code block above.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

According to [QDarkStyleSheet issue](https://github.com/ColinDuquesnoy/QDarkStyleSheet/issues/17), You could use:

```
QFrame[width="3"], QFrame[height="3]
```

These selectors, they seem to work cross-platform, and they are unlikely to change.
Probably better than using `enum` values as `ints`, as they are likely to change with Qt versions, and line styling are not, as they fulfill certain requirements.

Answer (score 1):

> but my app requires that i put everything in a single stylesheet that
>   gets loaded into the app.

You can use **Conflict Resolution**. Suppose that you have a **QMainWindow** object with lots of widgets on it . Set these style sheets for the **maindionw** style sheet :

```
QLabel#label{
    background-color: rgb(255, 170, 255);
}
QPushButton#pushButton{

    color: rgb(0, 0, 255);
}
QFrame#line{
    background-color: rgb(0, 170, 255);
}
```

The first css just changes a `QLabel` name *label* on your mainwindow and set its *back color* to **rgb(255, 170, 255)**. The next will change text color of a `QPushButton` named *pushButton* to (0,0,255);. The third one change property of a line.Lines are just a QFrame.
So the solution that I can offer is to place your css in a file and then load this file using `QFile` and `QTextStream` and then set the contents of the file for css of your main winodw or main widget using `setStyleSheet ( const QString & styleSheet )` function. or If you are using creator just right click on your main window and select **change stylesheet** and then paste your css. **But bear in mind that you should use conflict resolution**.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question on how i should get to the properties of a HLine or VLine. With Conflict Resolution, i could do:

    QFrame#Line
{
color: red;
}

And this will succesfully change the line color to red, but if i add a 2nd line, this will be default. The idea of the single CSS file is that whenever we want to create another app with the same look, we can just load in the CSS and all elements will be the same, without labeling


Also, on a side note...why is everyone using RGB? What's wrong with HEX?

Comment: I'm not css expert but I know that you can have classes and IDs. Here there is the same concepts. If your are gonna change a class of objects line QPushButtons use QPushButton{...} and if you want to change just one of your buttons use QPushButton#name_of_btn{...}. hmmm using RGB ! That is just because creator's wizard for creating css rules use RGB.:)

Comment: Okay, i feel really dumb at the moment.... i found out that just using LINE is enough to change the propperties of a HLine and VLine. I was looking for something difficult like QLine or QHLine, or QFrame::HLine.... it's just LINE...argh...

Thank you for your time saeed, it wasn't really the answer i was looking for, but it eventually led me to looking at the CLASS table in the Object Inspector.

Answer (score 0):

You can leave Qt's hlines and build up your own very easy. For frames you want looks like hline add property "class" as "HLine" (for example), in designer or in c++ code:

```
frame->setProperty("class", "HLine")
```

.
Then, you can define in main view's or in global app stylesheet something like this:

```
QFrame.HLine {
    border: none;
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
```

and you will get horizontal two pixels red line.